# What is the category of coherent sheaves on a logarithmic scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves, homological-dimension

I try to learn basic things on logarithmic geometry, and in particular I don't find much on the category of coherent sheaves on a logarithmic scheme: is it a notion that makes sense or differ from coherent sheaves on the underlying scheme?

If such a category exists, do we have nice homological properties, such as being of homological dimension $n$ for a *log* smooth projective variety of dimension $n$?

Maybe it is interesting to consider some kind of parabolic sheaves?

Any reference on the subject is welcome!

Comment: A good starting point would be Talpo--Vistoli, Infinite root stacks and quasi-coherent sheaves on logarithmic schemes.

Comment: Niziol's article http://www.math.utah.edu/~niziol/klog11.pdf has a section 3. Coherent and locally free sheaves on log-schemes